# How to make index page for Area [ASP MVC]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to make a index page for my admin area , and I have no idea about that , tried to search but did not got any solution for that ...

here is a picture of my area :

[image]

Simply I want to make my area index like this :

```
http://localhost/admin
```

and I'll customize the index page for that path ...

thanks

Comment: just add a `HomeController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a HomeController with a Index action inside returning the View you want.

Or, assuming that your default action is defined in one of the existing controllers, just add it when registering the Area (for example, a Index action on the BooksController):

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context){
    context.MapRoute(
        name: "Default", 
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
        defaults: new 
        {
            area = "Admin",
            controller = "Books", 
            action = "Index", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional 
       });
}
```